# Можно ли сделать Активити в полэкрана?

Tags: android, java

Можно ли сделать Активити в полэкрана, чтобы была видна Активити предыдущая?

Например, делаю Активити1 (во весь экран) и Активити2 (в треть экрана).
Активити2 - это типа меню, со стандартными button.

На Активити1, слева, тонкая полоска какого-нибудь ViewImage. При касании этой полоски, выпрыгивает Активити2 (меню).

Можно так сделать или я изобретаю велосипед?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фрагменты. Вам нужны [фрагменты](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/fragment.php)!

А если нужно заделать меню, которое выдвигается, то можно использовать эту [либу](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

Comment: @nekaneka, зачем либа для меню, если есть стандартный, гугловый, NavigationDrawer?

Comment: Благодарю! Буду пробовать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в таком случае либа и правда не нужна.